# Having transmission problems

Tags: pontiac

my Pontiac g6 doesn't want to shift after the car is driven for awhile , but when co0ld nit shifts just fine, any ideas ?
haven't tried anything , not sure what to do

Comment: have you checked the trans fluid level?

Answer (score 0):

Have the transmission fluid changed.  If you notice an improvement, have the fluid changed two more times, 500 miles apart.

I had the same problem, which was resolved once the valve body was rebuilt.

Comment: So the real answer may be to rebuild the valve body...